# How to disable a button according to state of input with email pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a login form with 2 input field and login button, one of the input field has email pattern for valid emails. If one of the input fields are empty then login button is becoming disabled. But my problem is that in case of wrong email pattern is entered, error message appears but the button does not become disable.

Here is the scenario:[image]

here is my template code for this part:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" required #email="ngModel" class="input-field-background form-control" [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched" [(ngModel)]="user.email" pattern="^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

    </div>
    <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.invalid && email.touched)">
        <small class="error-text" *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</small>
        <small class="error-text" *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">Enter a valid email</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input #password="ngModel" required type="password" [class.is-invalid]="password.invalid && password.touched" class="input-field-background form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <small class="error-text" [class.d-none]="password.valid || password.untouched">Password is required</small>
    </div>
    <small class="error-text">{{msg}}</small>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="login-button btn btn-info" [disabled] = "!user.email || !user.password">Login</button>
      <small class="small-style float-right" [routerLink]="['/registration']">New User ? Register here</small>
    </div>
  </form>
```

How can I solve this problem ? Is there a way to solve that simply on template file or should I make some operations on the corresponding .ts file like assigning a new variable or a boolean etc...

Comment: Have you tried `[disabled]="loginForm.invalid"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris Garsonn, you can check email validation in your submit button.

```
[disabled] = "!user.email || email.invalid || !user.password"
```